# $f, g$ continuous in $[a, b]$, differentiable in (a, b), then there exists $c \in (a, b)$ such that $[f(b) - f(a)]g'(c) = [g(b) - g(a)]f'(c)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

If $f, g$ are continuous real functions in $[a, b]$, differentiable in (a, b), then there exists $c \in (a, b)$  such that $[f(b) - f(a)]g'(c) = [g(b) - g(a)]f'(c)$

I tried to define $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$ and apply the mean theorem, but it didn't work... I also tried to define $h(x) = f(x)g(x)$ and apply the mean theorem and it didn't work either. I guess I do not have to use the mean theorem... Actually, the mean theorem is a consequence of this result, right?

Does someone know how to prove this exercise? It would be really helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: This is Cauchy's mean value theorem. It's given as an exercise?

Comment: And yes, the Mean Value Theorem which can commonly be found in Stewart's Calculus textbooks is a consequence of this statement (if you take $g:[a,b]\rightarrow [a,b]$ given by $g(x)=x$).

Comment: here is a nice simple video explaining it: http://www.larsoncalculus.com/calc10/content/proof-videos/chapter-8/section-7/proof-the-extended-mean-value-theorem/

Answer (score 1):

Use $$ h(x) = [f(b) - f(a)] g(x) - [g(b) - g(a)] f(x) .$$  (In other words, replace the $c$ with the independent variable to define $h$, so that when you apply the Mean Value Theorem to $h$, the theorem will give you the desired $c$.)  Notice that $h(a) = h(b)$ (both equal $f(a) g(b) - f(b) g(a)$), so the Mean Value Theorem (or Rolle's Theorem) give you $c \in (a,b)$ such that $h'(c) = 0$.  But $h'(c) = [f(b) - f(a)] g'(c) - [g(b) - g(a)] f'(c)$, so there you go.

Incidentally, people often phrase this theorem (Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem) with the conclusion that $$ \frac{f'(c)} {g'(c)} = \frac{f(b) - f(a)} {g(b) - g(a)} .$$  For this, you need some fine print to guarantee that this won't involve division by zero (such as that $g' \ne 0$ on $(a,b)$), but your version without division is nice because it works regardless of that.